# Prove $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^2}\ln\left[\frac{(1+x^2)^2}{1-x^2}\right]dx=\pi$

Tags: integration

Most integrals involved $\ln(x)$ seem to produced results of $\pi^2$, $\sqrt\pi$, $\pi\ln(2)$ etc, but rarely $\pi$ on its own.

Here is one

(1)
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^2}\ln\left[\frac{(1+x^2)^2}{1-x^2}\right]dx=\pi$$

I can't remembered where I got the idea to prompted me to search for this result. Anyway, if anyone got integrals involving $\ln(x)$ that give simple $\pi$ answer I would like to see it.

Can anyone prove (1)?

---

An attempt, using integration by parts

$$=\int_{0}^{1}2x^{-2}\ln(1+x^2)dx-\int_{0}^{1}x^{-2}\ln(1-x^2)dx$$

$$=\left.(-x^{-1})\ln(1+x^2)\right|_{0}^{1}+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2}{1+x^2}dx+\left.(-x^{-1})\ln(1-x^2)\right|_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2}{1-x^2}dx$$

$$=-\ln(2)+\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2}{1-x^2}dx$$

I am just stuck, the last integral doesn't make sense to me, I am keep getting zero answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the last integral....

$\dfrac{2}{1-x^2} = \dfrac{2}{(1+x)(1+x)} = \dfrac{1}{1-x} + \dfrac{1}{1+x}\\
\int\dfrac{1}{1-x} + \dfrac{1}{1+x} dx = \ln(1+x) - \ln (1-x)$

But that doesn't converge as at 1.

However,  $x^{-1} \ln(1-x^2)$ doesn't converge at 1 either.

but, $-x^{-1} \ln(1-x^2) - \ln(1+x) + \ln (1-x) = (1-x^{-1}) \ln(1-x) - (1+x^{-1}) \ln(1+x)\\
\frac{(x-1)\ln(1-x)}{x} - \frac{(1+x)\ln(1+x)}{x}|_0^1 = -2\ln2$

Going back another step, I it looks like you dropped a factor of 2.

$\int_{0}^{1}2x^{-2}\ln(1+x^2)dx-\int_{0}^{1}x^{-2}\ln(1-x^2)dx\\
(-2x^{-1})\ln(1+x^2)+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{4}{1+x^2}dx-[(-x^{-1})\ln(1-x^2)-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2}{1-x^2}dx]\\
-2 \ln 2 + 4\tan^{-1} 1 + 2 \ln 2 = \pi$